# What is the consequence of reading synchronously from an asynchronous named pipe?

Tags: windows, winapi, named-pipes

In my application, I'd like to use asynchronous pipe open but use synchronous reading and writing.

Is this mixed usage supported and if yes, are there any repercussions to it? I don't find this documented and I wouldn't know what to test for. I can see that this might have performance or correctness issues that a casual test might not detect.

Comment: synchronous I/O - this is asynchronous I/O + wait in place if `STATUS_PENDING` returned.  so you canby self do this wait if open in asynchronous mode. but what sense do this ?

Comment: there are no consequences and cannot be. what does it mean supported? how you write - so it will be.

Comment: I'd like most code to be synchronous for simplicity and performance (there are many call sites for pipe IO scattered through the application). That's the reason I'm hesitating to enable async mode. I mean, there must be a downside or else async mode would always be enabled.

Comment: synchronous of course more simply but perfomance of it not better. *I mean, there must be a downside or else async mode would always be enabled.* - no any downside from asynchronous file mode. faster visa versa - synchronous i/o have downside - all operation on file will be serialized. new operation not begin, until  current not complete. this can lead to deadlock.